Can't select the product I've just added in Salesforce to the Price Book
I can create a new product, and it's definitely active.
When I try to add it to the Standard Price book (also active) it doesn't appear as an option to select. Same for any custom price book - all price books are also active.
I have Salesforce admin profile and (I think) full permissions.
Where is my product? What else can I try so it shows up? Is there some other object I should be adding it too? Puzzling me.

thanks, will do

I've resolved this now, maybe this will help someone else! I couldn't add the product to the price book as it didn't have a price book entry - and the price book entry related list/button had been removed from the page layout so it didn't prompt me to think about this. I've now been into the page layout to add it back on, add the price book entries and therefore it's now available to be selected for the various Price Books. Nice to find the reason!
